# INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI Spotify Clone Error

Tags: clone, spotify

I'm having a problem with this repository cloned on my computer:
https://github.com/JL978/spotify-clone-server
and also:
https://github.com/JL978/spotify-clone-client

In the clone server, I start the npm and a get the 'listening on port: 4000' message, but when I run the spotify-clone-client, I get the interface as normal, but when I click the log in button, I get the 'INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI' error. I also put the correct things in the .env file:

```
CLIENT_ID = (I wrote the client id on my Spotify dev dashboard here)
CLIENT_SECRET = (I revealed and wrote the client secret on my Spotify dev dashboard here)
FRONT_URI = http://localhost:3000
RE_URI = http://localhost:4000/callback
REXP = /\.localhost:3000/
```

Also, in the Spotify Dev dashboard, in the 'Edit Settings' section, I added 'http://localhost:4000/callback' to the text field of the 'Redirect URIs'. I didn't change anything else in the source code (mentioned above), but I get the error. In the repository's README file, there's nothing else that needs to be done, or am I overlooking?

P.S: I'm new to developing, so I started off with cloning.

Comment: I searched for which possible duplicates this post has, but I couldn't find any. Can you at least comment a possible duplicate if you know one please?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Git or GitHub. The repository you've cloned is *on* GitHub, but it's all stuff to do with Spotify itself. (I don't know anything more than that.)